# Check in android if facebook-mail exists or not

Tags: android, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I want to check in my android app if the user's email Facebook exists or not and if it's not exist, set it as "No mail found".
The code is right but when I click the Facebook button nothing happened because my inexistent email cause an error.
I have already check with my user token and my Facebook account doesn't have an email. Obviously it works perfectly without the email string.

This is my code:

```
loginButtonFb.setReadPermissions("user_friends", "email");
    loginButtonFb.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId(),
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                                login_name = data.getString("name");
                                String idFb = data.getString("id");
                                String mailFb = data.getString("email");
                                String method = "loginFb";
                                BackgroundTaskLogin backgroundTask = new BackgroundTaskLogin(mContext);
                                backgroundTask.execute(method, login_name, idFb, mailFb);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Login attempt canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Login attempt failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure your API access has the right to acquire the user's e-mail address?

Comment: yes, I don't have email for Facebook, I have already verified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I have declared String mailFb as universal String.
The other part of the code is below:

```
 loginButtonFb.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId(),
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                                login_name = data.getString("name");
                                String idFb = data.getString("id");
                                if(!data.isNull("email")){
                                mailFb = data.getString("email");
                                }
                                mailFb = "Mail not found";
                                String method = "loginFb";
                                BackgroundTaskLogin backgroundTask = new BackgroundTaskLogin(mContext);
                                backgroundTask.execute(method, login_name, idFb, mailFb);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();

        }
```